# Writing two job responsibilities at work

Tags: resume, developer

How can one write his job title in the CV if I have two responsibilities at work like : CRM Developer / .Net Developer ? 
Should it be like?

Title: CRM / .Net Developer

OR should I only write one of them as a title then below in the description write the other ?

Comment: Instead of /, use &. That should make it pretty obvious you did both things. Right?

Answer (score 1):

In a resume you should **always use your official title.** This is to avoid appearing to misrepresent yourself and to avoid problems during reference checks.

A typical job history on a resume will list the company name, your actual title, year range and *then* your responsibilities and accomplishments in a bulleted list.

Even if you have two main roles, you will still be registered in the system or known to HR by a single title: (Junior/Senior) Developer, Consultant, Architect, etc. If you don't know your title, check your offer letter or contract or the description of the position when you originally applied for the job.

Here's a sample job history. Ignore the responsibilities I list and forgive the lousy formating, StackExchange markdown is rather limited.

> - CRM Solutions Inc. - Senior Consultant - 2014-Present
>
>   - something something CRM
>   - bla bla .Net bla bla
>   - ...
> - Acme Co. - Developer - 2012-2014 // Junior Developer - 2011-2012
>
>   - something something CRM ... using .Net ...
>   - ...

Comment: I agree, always use the official title in the heading

Answer (score -1):

It all depends what impression you want to convey - what do you want your next role to be? What job are you applying for with this CV?

If you want to emphasise your CRM credentials, you could use something like

> 2015-2016 **CRM Developer, Acme Corp**
>
> Worked on a number of .NET-based CRMs in the Widget Division.

If you want to emphasise that you're a .NET developer, you could use something like

> 2015-2016 **.NET Developer, Acme Corp**
>
> Development work for a number of CRMs in the Widget Division.

or if you want to emphasise the fact that you're an all-rounder who can do both, you could use something like

> 2015-2016 **.NET & CRM Developer, Acme Corp**
>
> Worked on a number of .NET-based CRMs in the Widget Division.